# perfomance between timer vs for loop in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I try to testing my Swing GUI run on Raspberry PI. My goal is every 1 sec show system time. and every "cycleTime" seconds update "planValue".Test on Desktop it's normal. When I run on RaspPI it's very slow and time delay when update "planValue" or open popup new Dialog.

**This is MainScreen class**

```
public class MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelPlan;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelSysTime;
    int planValue;
    int cycleTime = 5; //5 seconds
    int counter = 1;

    public MainScreen() {
        initComponents();
        //start timer.
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        showDisplay();
    }

    public void showDisplay() {
        DateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        jLabelSysTime.setText(formatTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        jLabelPlan.setText(String.valueOf(planValue));
    }
}
```

If I create new Timer planTimer

```
Timer planTimer = new Timer(cycleTime * 1000, new ActionListener() {   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        planValue += 1;
    }
});
planTimer.start(); //Timer updPlan start
```

or use loop in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    showDisplay();
        if(counter == cycleTime) {
            planValue += 1;
            counter = 1;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestion? or best solution to run my GUI on Raspberri PI. thanks.

Comment: `javax.swing.Timer` is sufficient for what you looking for. Look also on `javax.swing.SwingWorker`. Dont use loop. Instead make the timer to fire the after every `1` second.

Comment: `showDisplay` maybe should end in `repaint(10L);` as that is what you intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your timer to fire event repeatedly using [`Timer.setRepeats(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29).

```
Timer planTimer = new Timer(cycleTime * 1000, new ActionListener() {   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        planValue += 1;
    }
});
plainTimer.setRepeats(true);//Set repeatable.
planTimer.start();
```

And your `timer` variable should be like this:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        showDisplay();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

Comment: What shoud I do javax.swing.Timer timer when I use only 1 Timer(planTimer) my sysTime refresh every 5sec.

Comment: Since there is a mismatch between repeat delay in two actions so I would suggest you to use two Timers for each one.

Comment: Yes; for efficiency, the two timers will "perform their waiting using a single, shared thread."

Comment: @trashgod: Yeah you pointed out the most dominant characteristic of `javax.swing.Timer`